# ORA - 29532: Java swing call inside of PL/SQL function

Tags: java, oracle, swing, plsql, joptionpane

Is it possible call `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog();` inside of PL/SQL Function

Java source code in PL/SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "Hello" AS
import javax.swing.*;
public class Hello
{
  public static String world()
  {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hello!");
    return "Hello world";
  }
};
```

Create PL/SQL function, for call JOptionPane:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION helloworld
RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'Hello.world ()
return java.lang.String';
```

Call PL/SQL function in anonymous block:

```
DECLARE

v_java VARCHAR2(500);

BEGIN

 v_java := helloworld();
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Text');  

END;
```

Comment: Java inside Oracle runs on the *server* side. The server normally doesn't even have a graphics card. Even if it's on your own personal computer, Oracle is normally running in a process that doesn't have access to the GUI, which is attached to the login session, while Oracle runs in a daemon or service.

Comment: If the problem you're really trying to solve is *"How can I run a GUI from my oracle stored procedures?"* please consider Oracle Apex. [Find out more](https://apex.oracle.com/en/)